# Update a seekbar using layout inflater

Tags: android, layout, seekbar

I have a seekbar which I need to update from a service. However the cursor doesn't move at all.
Here is the code (you can see lots of layout because I put just the code you need, but there are also other view objects in these layouts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarTime"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements Runnable {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private SeekBar seekBarTime;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //SET SEEKBAR
        LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService( LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.play_song , null);
        seekBarTime = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBarTime);
        seekBarTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = this;
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    // Seekbar
    public void run() {     
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {


            int currentPosition = 0;
            int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            seekBarTime.setMax(total);
            currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            Log.w("disgustingapps", currentPosition + " / " + total);

            seekBarTime.setProgress(currentPosition);

        }

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

The logcat assure me that currentPosition and total are not empty. However nothing happen.
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I tested your `run()` method and on my side and the SeekBar updates nicely.
Where do you create and start the `MediaPlayer`?

The run() method is checking if the mediaplayer is playing:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
...
}
```

But I don't see `mediaPlayer().start()`

Comment: I'm sure that it is playing in fact the logcat confirm it. But do you put the code in a Service or in an Activity?